# How can I network with other developers on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, social-networking

So let's say I get an answer from someone who seems like a nice guy to have around and is open to contact after answering a question. How can I start networking with other developers who use Stack Overflow?

Messaging functionality isn't present. Does Stack Overflow end at the Q&A?

Comment: I can see that you have a blog on http://blogs.msdn.com/gisenberg and you got a contact form in there.

Comment: Visit http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/users-interested-in-social-networking-on-so

Answer (score 1):

Most of the guys here are also in twitter (http://twitter.com). If you have a twitter account, you can follow lots of developers.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Link to your **LinkedIn** page in your profile. Substitute "LinkedIn" for myspace, facebook, your blog, yada, and/or yada. Encourage others to do so as well (As I am doing now).

...

Step 3: Profit!

Comment: I don't like the idea, I'm thinking about privacy issues here, if you want to contact someone who is shy, you'll have a hard time, but adding message functionality, that person will feel safe but available at the same time.

Comment: Is there an SO linkedin group?  If not, there should be. :)

Answer (score 0):

Submit the question:  "How can I get in touch with *username*?"  Sure it'll be deleted within 10 seconds, but might catch their eye :-)

In all seriousness, the only thing you can do is click on their username to see their profile and hope they've added a website where you can find further info.

Answer (score 0):

For social networking on the site, you could try [this Greasemonkey script to add a friends list](http://nicksergeant.com/blog/programming/stack-overflow-friends-greasemonkey-script). I imagine that's a future planned feature, but this is a nice temporary bandaid.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave a comment at their answer asking for a contact details.

I wouldn't be surprised if J, J & Co. decide to add direct messages at some point, although I have not heard anything indicating they are planning on it.

As usual, Uservoice is a great place to nudge them in the "right" direction. :-)

Answer (score 0):

On their profile page, they could list a personal website, which may list further contact info.  It's a bit roundabout, but it's available.

Answer (score 0):

I should add my AIM to my About Me. I have my email, if for some reason, another SOer has a question for me off-site. I would suggest that. There is a user search and a more-than-generous About Me box on your profile. :)

Comment: What makes you think he was talking about you? :-)

Comment: 'Cause he's cool and has a High reputation ;)

Answer (score 0):

I join the club, be able to send "personal messages" and to add "contacts" would be super cool.

Following the privacy example that sites like Facebook gives, I would like to avoid giving my email adress(or other information) until I accept the user.

Also if you implement intrasite messages, you should and "ignore user" capability to.

Something very basic, just enough to get in touch and avoid getting touched.

Comment: This belongs to Uservoice as well.

Comment: Yes I know but I like to comment things first before committing something to uservoice, just so i can have something clear and useful instead of a silly idea.

Answer (score 0):

How about integrating most of the functionality between developers through facebook?

In that way you won't have to rewrite a good networking platform.

Most subfacebook communities like human pets are working like this. This creates more exposure in my opinion.

I would have said LinkedIn but other than networking I find that site to lack features.